# php : Issue on multidimensional array with PMA

Tags: php, regex, multidimensional-array, foreach

i'm working with **php** (**ubuntu** software).

I have some data into a **PMA** database, that i extract like this :

```
<?php
try
{
    $db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'dbName', 'dbPwd');
    mysql_select_db('dbName', $db);
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
        die('Erreur : '. $e->getMessage());
}

$sql = "SELECT p.ean13, pl.id_product, pl.name FROM $product_lang pl INNER JOIN $product p ON pl.id_product = p.id_product WHERE name LIKE '1 agapanthe %'";
$result_agpt = mysql_query($sql, $db);
$data = mysql_fetch_row($result_agpt);
```

Now that I have my data into an array like this :

**ean13 - id_product   - name**

NULL    - 5389  - 1 agapanthe ivoire //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
4027234262147 - 5387    - 1 agapanthe lilas ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    NULL - 5388     - 1 agapanthe parme ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    NULL - 5386     - 1 agapanthe violet //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

I want to display, **for each row** of my result, the following informations :

ean13 : NULL //// 
id_product : 5389 ////
product_name : 1 agapanthe ivoire

And for each of this row, i must **truncate** the name like this :
"1 agapanthe ivoire" => "1 agapanthe"
I'm doing this using the **preg_match** function, as below :

```
foreach($data as $value)
    {
        // preg_match to truncate product names : '1 agapanthe verte' => '1 agapanthe'

        $pattern = '/^(1\sagapanthe)\s(\w*)/is';
        $match_truncate = preg_match($pattern, $data[2], $matches);
        $name = $matches[1]; 
        echo "Name : ".$name; echo "<br />";echo "<br />";
        $attribute = $matches[2];
        echo "Attribut : ".$attribute; echo "<br />";
```

I tried several ways of doing this foreach, but i can't manage to make it work.

**EDIT** : My aim here is to truncate every name of my product, as to modify its content into PMA. Should I consider using PDO over mysql connection ?

Any help or comment would be greatly appreciated :) !

Regards,

Stelio Kontos.

Comment: (I'm a PHP beginner, be gentle please...!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have several issues here. First, and most important is stop using the `mysql` database extension. Instead use `mysqli` or `pdo`. The older `mysql` extension is deprecated in all supported version of PHP, and has been dropped from PHP 7.0.

Second the manner in which you built your SQL string is susceptible to SQL Injection. It is ***always*** a bad idea to concatenate data that could come from a user into an sql statement string. Even if it passes through the database first. Best way is to use parameterized sql strings which is available in `mysqli` and `pdo` (but not `mysql`).

Here is a link to the docs http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php

But to answer your question, using the `mysql` extension, the fetch needs to be inside the loop. It returns a single row at a time as an array with numerical indexes. So after:

```
$data = mysql_fetch_row($result_agpt);
```

`$data` will contain

```
[0] => 'NULL',
[1] => 5389,
[2] => '1 agapanthe ivoire'
```

The `foreach` is incorrect in this instance. You will need to do something more like

```
$data = mysql_fetch_row($result_agpt);
while($data !== false) {
    $ean13 = $data[0];
    $id = $data[1];
    $name = $data[2];

    // do something with it

    $data = mysql_fetch_row($result_agpt);
}
```

Finally, regular expressions are hard to get just right. I use an online regex tester like the one at https://regex101.com/ to make sure my patterns work. Here is one I think might work for you `/([0-9]+ \w+) (\w+)/is`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for these security advice ! I'm gonna get through PDO right away. And I think what you said about my foreach statement might solve my problem. I'm using http://www.phpliveregex.com/ to test my regular expressions, i find it cleaner to use than the others :).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand the question properly, but if you want to display only portion of the value from the database column pl.name, you could rework the SQL query:

```
$sql = "SELECT p.ean13, pl.id_product, '1 agapanthe' FROM $product_lang pl INNER JOIN $product p ON pl.id_product = p.id_product WHERE name LIKE '1 agapanthe %'"
```

The above query will display always `1 agapanthe` as product name, no need for complex regular expressions here ;)

**EDIT:**

You can provide the portion for the `LIKE` clause dynamically and then use it to select it as column:

```
$like = "something";
$sql = "SELECT p.ean13, pl.id_product, '".$like."' FROM $product_lang pl INNER JOIN $product p ON pl.id_product = p.id_product WHERE name LIKE '".$like."%'";
```

Also - **do not forget** to escape the contents, if they are going to be user-defined or **use prepared statements and PDO** to access/query your database. This way you will be protected from SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Is it a good way to do it :o ? I'm doing this for a particular product here, but later i'd like my script to manage every product of my database (thus the regex). What i was wondering is : how to build the foreach statement to display ean13, id and name for every row ?

Comment: What do you mean by hard coding ? like overkill ?

Comment: I also did edit my question,  as it seems i wans't clear enough about what i want. 
Your part of answer is interesting, in the way that I could pass my pattern into a variable just like you did.
My problem is regarding the structure of my foreach statement... I don't know how to build it to get my 4 rows on screen, and then I truncate the product_name.

Comment: Hard coding is the use of a literal constant. It is called that because the code must be changed when the literal changes. In many places, folks will put in a literal constant because they are convenient at the time, but they might as well be carved in stone because once they get into production you can't change them without going through a complete change cycle. That should include testing to make sure the change to the literal doesn't break something elsewhere in the program or that the same literal value wasn't neglected somewhere else in the program.

Comment: Okay, thanks again for this lesson ! I will keep that in mind :).